# How can I remove all popups?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to remove popups coming out of excel files?And messages like

```
"excel 2010 excel has detected a problem with this file. opening it may be dangerous".

"Office has detected a problem with this file.Editing may harm your computer".
```

In a way safe way??I have few "xlt" files and as soon as I open I get above messages.Please some one tell me how to remove in a safer way without harming files.I have many files that throws error like this.

Please suggest some answers.

Answer (score 1):

The chances are good you are seeing these messages because of the older file format; `xlt`. Or there could quite literally be some damage to the file.

If these are your own files which you know and trust, add the location to the Trust Center - [Add, remove, or modify a trusted location for your files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-remove-or-modify-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010354311.aspx).

[image]

For more information about why you are seeing the messages - [What is Protected View?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx)

Comment: Charlie:I have done this,i have added the folder.But still the same problem.And thanks for the link.

Comment: Have you tried to save the file to a newer version to see if that fixes it? Otherwise, the file may just be damaged and need to be recreated.

Comment: CharlieRB: I tried to save to older version,still same problem.But in case if the file is damaged,i`m able to open it and edit.

Comment: After you open and edit, did you try to save to the new version using `File > Save & Send > Change File Type > Template (*.xltx)`?

Comment: :I just tried it,it was asking to save without micro.I did it and opened but it said like "Macros are disabled".

Comment: You need to change macro security to avoid that. Did you get the original error?

Comment: Charlie:I completly enabled macros.I have put low security.

Comment: Did it work? Are you still getting the original error message you asked about?